# What's the difference between Finite State Machine and Stage Event Driven Archtecture

Tags: architecture, state-machine

I know the FSM is a combination of states + triggers + actions. and we implemented a async fsm which may support a pool of threads to run actions asynchronously. and when I checked the SEDA [paper](https://github.com/mdwelsh/mdwelsh.github.io/blob/master/papers/seda-sosp01.pdf) -

I understand the seda is stages which each stage may contains a standalone thread pool and a standalone queue.
is this the only difference? or is the stage contains a FSM? what I think is: the SEDA stage is more complex than FSM and each stage may contains a FULL FSM (like what I said, a thread pool + states). Is it correct?